# pre-compilation issue in handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, handlebars.js

I am using handlebar 1.3.0. i tried to pre-compile the handlebar template with the command

```
handlebars aa.tpl -f aa.js
```

i am getting the output given below. In the compiled .js file, there is no html tags present in the source template file.

```
(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.template, 
    templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
})();
```

is there any  problem with the tool?

Answer (score 2):

we have to mention the extension of the source file in the command line

```
handlebars --extension=tpl aa.tpl -f aa.js
```